# Binary versus ASCII representation of a hash - which is more secure

Tags: hash

I am using SHA256 to create a hash.  Output is captured as a text string (thus "A245B6FF") and that is what has been used to create the digital signature.  Since the hash could have been captured as binary and the binary representation used to create the digital signature, which is more secure and is there a specific standard to dictate the use of binary instead of a text string?  Issues have been seen on the receiving end trying to decrypt the signature with the public key.

To clarify - I am looking for a standard that would state what the sign and/or decrypt action requires.  The signature created from the ASCII representation is different (as expected) from the signature created from the binary representation of the hash.  The problem comes in "decrypting" the signature to get back to the original hash.  The signature appears to be invalid based on our attempts to "decrypt" and compare to the original hash - thus our concern as to what is the standard.  If I have to understand that your hash was an ASCII value in order to decrypt it properly, then I feel I don't have a standard signature.

And we have two totally different applications (one sending and the other receiving).

Answer (score 2):

It's just a convenience factor, there is no security difference.

They are one-to-one convertible. Any "*issues*" would just be the expertise of the user.

Answer (score 0):

It's still a little unclear to me exactly what you are asking.

Also, asking compound questions can make your questions unclear to the people trying to answer.

> which is more secure

Which what? Which format for the SHA256 hash? I assume this is what you are asking about. From a usability perspective the "ASCII" encoded version is probably easier for most people (human users) to work with. If this matters to you from a security perspective then you could say one is more secure than the others, but if not then not.

> and is there a specific standard to dictate the use of the actual binary instead of a text string?

Usage of "actual binary" for what part? Here it is not so clear since you also mention digital signatures. What I think you mean is that you have an ASCII-encoded SHA256 value or a list of multiple ASCII-encoded SHA256 values and you are going to sign this with a private key. If this is what you are asking about, then again the main difference is usability. If you are distributing the list of SHA256 values as a text file that users might look at then you might want to use ASCII-encoded values since the binary values might look weird to users. On the other hand, if this is all done programmatically then I think there is no significant difference. (You only use half as much memory if you use binary instead of ASCII-hex, but I think most people would not care much about gaining back 32-bytes or so of memory.)

I am not aware of a standard that dictates one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

The question is kind of like asking "which is a more secure way to store your phone number: in Roman numerals, or in French words?" They're just two different ways to represent exactly the same information, and do not influence security at all. Encodings - not to be confused with *ciphers*, which are actual encryption - do not require any secret (such as a *key*) to reverse or convert between. The following are all encodings (and thus equivalent, security-wise) for binary data:

- Hex (a.k.a. base16); what you have here
- Decimal (base10); uncommon for very large values such as hash digests, but you can do it.
- Base64 (more compact than hex or decimal, but case-sensitive and requires punctuation)
- Binary digits (a.k.a. bits, "0s and 1s", base2)

In addition to those, "non-encoded" binary values can be stored within a program, in a file, or passed between functions. They can't be represented as text without encoding them in some way, though, any more than a paperback book can represent a particular instance of a song such that a reader would hear it without converting it back to an audio file or passing it through some decoder first.

However, when passing values of any kind (including binary) between programs or parts of a program, the consumer needs to expect the format that the caller/writer provides. I put "scare quotes" on "non-encoded" above because it turns out that even within a computer, there's multiple ways to represent binary values (for example, there's [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)) and it's important to match expectations. Getting back to the question at hand, **you need to check what format your `sign` function expects the hash in**, and ensure the output of your hash function is in that format (converting if needed) before passing it to the `sign` function.

The only way this could impact security is if you're using a poorly-designed signing function that does something stupid like assume the input is some dense format (possibly raw binary, in a type-unsafe language) and ignore any portion of the input beyond the expected length. Of course, a well-designed signing function generally won't expect you to perform any hashing yourself - you'll tell it "sign this data with RSA-SHA256" and pass it the data and RSA private key, and it'll do the hash and signing itself - so your library *is* somewhat suspect. As a general rule, if you find yourself invoking RSA (or ECC) primitives (the actual math) directly, you should probably be using a better library.

Comment: Also, another reason why base 10 is uncommon is because it doesn't result in a fixed length for any value, unlike binary or hexadecimal